# Find specific value's count in a vector

Tags: arrays, matlab

I generate a vector of 20 random integers in 1 : 6. For more clarity: `d = floor ( 6 * rand ( 1 , 20 )  + 1)`. How can I count the numbers of sixes with MATLAB?

Answer (score 5):

Just use this -

```
count = nnz(d==6)
```

One of the uses of [`nnz`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/nnz.html) is to count the number of matches found. In this case, it would do comparisons between every element of `d` with `6` and return a logical array of `ones` or `zeros` based on the matches being found or not respectively and then `nnz` would count the number of occurrences of `ones`. `nnz` is really a very efficient tool for such cases, try exploring it.

Answer (score 1):

```
nnz(d==6)
```

As given by [Divakar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22722000/1536976) is great. But using `sum` is usually faster:

```
sum(d(:)==6)
```

Example:

```
d = floor ( 6 * rand ( 1 , 2e6 ) + 1);
tic;nnz(d==6);toc;
tic;sum(d(:)==6);toc;
```

gives:

```
Elapsed time is 0.020109 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.012709 seconds.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to count the number of occurrences of a single value then use `nnz(d==6)` as @Divakar suggested, but if you want to count the total number of *multiple* values, 3s *and* 6s say, you can do that with [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html):

```
num3s6s = nnz(ismember(d,[3 6]))
```

same as:

```
num3s6s = nnz(d==3 | d==6)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to obtain the count of each value: use [`histc`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/histc.html):

```
d = [1 2 4 2 3 4 5 4 3 6]; %// example data
values = 1:6; %// values you want the count of
count = histc(d, values);
```

This gives

```
count =
     1     2     2     3     1     1
```